# How to make variable available in parent shell after execution

Tags: bash, shell, export, sh, parent-child

Below is the simplified shell script a.sh :-

```
function init(){
    export aData="Data of a"
    echo "init of a"
}

function execute(){
    init
    echo "execute of a >$aData<"
}

$@
```

and this shell script is invoked by below alias :-

```
alias ae="sh a.sh execute"
```

executing ae gives below result :-

> init of a
>
> execute of a >Data of a<

Once the execution is finished. Now accessing aData from the same terminal give no results :-

```
echo $aData
```

prints nothing, even though aData is exported in the init method.

Requirement is to have access to $aData after the execution of execute method of a.sh but no access should be available to init and execute method.

Kindly suggest.

Comment: A child process has no access to the parent process' memory space.

Comment: @mogli : If you have to pass it to the parent process (and can't do with sourcing the script, as vera suggested), you could write the intended value of the environment variable to a file and have the parent script read this file for setting the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `source` builtin command instead:

your `a.sh` should look like:

```
function init(){
export aData="Data of a"
echo "init of a"
}

function execute(){
    init
    echo "execute of a >$aData<"
}
```

and you can call execute function this way in a sh shell:

```
alias ae=". a.sh; execute"
```

or within a bash shell
    alias ae="source a.sh; execute"

Be aware that all functions defined in `a.sh` will then be defined in the parent shell (eg. init, execute, ...). To avoid such situation (which may lead to function name collision), you can use the following `t2.sh` script:

```
case "$1" in
    execute)
        export aData="Data of a"
        echo "init of a"
        ;;
    anyother_command_to_exec)
        # code
        ;;
    *);;
esac
```

and run the command

```
alias ae2=". a2.sh execute"
```

Comment: if the logic in execute case is complex, and consist of multiple function calls, then those function calls will be available in the parent shell, which might result in function name collision. Kindly suggest.